# What is equi-derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, definition

I encountered on the internet the property equi-derivative in the context of real-analysis. But now later, I can't find a proper definition somewhere. Could someone state me a proper definition?

There is no Wikipedia page of equi-derivative, and if I do a quick google search than I stumble across academic papers that I find incomprehensible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix a set $S \subset \mathbb{R}$. For $s \in S$, let $f_s : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be locally integrable functions. We will say that this collection $(f_s)$ is *approximately equicontinuous* at $x$ if there exists $M > 0$ and $r >0$ such that for all $(s,t) \in S \times (x-r, x+r)$, we have $| f_s(t) | < M$.

Givens such an approximately equicontinuous family, the functions $f_s$ are called the *equi-derivatives at $x$*.

Comment: Thanks!!! Does the definition apply to both Riemann-integrable and Lebesgue-integrable?

Comment: @drandran12 I'm not an expert, but I can't see why _locally integrable_ would favor any particular measure.